# Brokered UWP Component Project Templates and Async

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, winrt-component

I am playing with Brokered UWP Component Project Templates (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2e9cac0-66a8-464a-a902-55ae765c8e6e), and testing if I can call asynchronous method from the brokered component.

So I replaced BrokeredComponent1 class :

```
namespace Server
{
    public sealed class BrokeredComponent1
    {
        public string GetValue()
        {
            return "Hello .NET world";
        }
    }
}
```

by :

```
namespace Server
{
    public sealed class BrokeredComponent1
    {    
        public IAsyncOperation<string> GetValueAsync()
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return "Hello .NET world";
            }).AsAsyncOperation();
        }
    }
}
```

And then called it in MainPage in Button_Click method like this :

```
string brokeredComponentValue = await bc.GetValueAsync();
```

Everything seems to work in Debug Mode ("Hello .NET world" appears after 3 seconds), but I'm unable to make it work in Release Mode, app just crash when I click the button.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that UseDotNetNativeToolchain was default set to true in csproj in Realease mode.